# Updating component values when service value changes Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an Angular 8 project with two sibling components that both use a service to update restaurant data. Essentially, I have one component showing a list of restaurants grabbed from an api, and a sibling component that can filter the restaurants that get shown by the first component. I am using a service to get and set the list of restaurants, but my code is currently not populating any data on load. Here's the code for my components and service

Resturant.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class EatstreetService {

  radius;
  address;
  public restaurants: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public setRestaurant(){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('method', 'delivery');
    params = params.append('pickup-radius', this.radius);
    params = params.append('street-address', this.address);
    params = params.append('access-token', this.token)
    this.restaurants.next(this.httpClient.get(`https://api.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search`, {params}))
  }


  public getRestaurant(): Observable<any>{

    return this.restaurants.asObservable();
  }
}
```

ResturantsFilter.component.ts

```
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurants;
  radius;
  address;

  constructor(private eatstreetService: EatstreetService) { }

  setRestaurants() {
    this.eatstreetService.setRestaurant()
  }

  getRestaurants() {
    this.eatstreetService.getRestaurant().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data['restaurants']);
      this.restaurants = data['restaurants'];
    })
  }

  onSelect(): void {
    this.setRestaurants()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setRestaurants()
    this.getRestaurants()
  }

}
```

ResturantsList.component.ts

```
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurants;

  constructor(private eatstreetService: EatstreetService) { }

  getRestaurants() {
    this.eatstreetService.getRestaurant().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data['restaurants']);
      this.restaurants = data['restaurants'];
    })
  }
  setRestaurants() {
    this.eatstreetService.setRestaurant()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRestaurants()
  }
}
```

I have found many related questions about this, but none of the solutions are working for me.

Comment: Does the http get request give you the data you want ? I mean, if you put it in a console.log, before putting it in the BehaviorSubject, what do you get ?

Comment: Ok, good. Do you really need to the getRestaurant method from the service to do the subscribe ?
You could do in ResturantsList and ResturantsFilter something like this.eatstreetService.restaurants.subscribe(blabla...) as it's already observable due to BehaviorSubject type

Comment: It returns an observable but no data. However, if I don't make this.restaurants an observable it console logs the desired list of restaurants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to emit the value through your BehaviorSubject after your http get response :

```
 @Injectable()
    export class EatstreetService {

      radius;
      address;
      public restaurants: = new ReplaySubject(1);

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

      public setRestaurant(){
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('method', 'delivery');
        params = params.append('pickup-radius', this.radius);
        params = params.append('street-address', this.address);
        params = params.append('access-token', this.token)
        this.httpClient.get(`https://api.com/publicapi/v1/restaurant/search`, {params})
                     .subscribe(resp => this.restaurants.next(resp) ) ;

      }


      public getRestaurant(): Observable<any>{

        return this.restaurants.asObservable();
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is giving me a "TypeError:  Cannot read property 'restaurants' of null" on load. It works if I call setResturants() after load however.

Comment: this is because the first emitted value is null, you need to use ReplaySubject instead of BehaviorSubject, I updated my answer.